# Is it a good practice to use multiple "AND" in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL. I have a question. Is it safe and a good practice to use multiple "AND" logic operator in MYSQL? If no, please share some good practices.

Here's an example of the command:
`$is_deleted = 0; (still available)`
`location = "RACK 1 - A1";`
`$id = 45;`

`SELECT location FROM items WHERE is_deleted = ? AND location = ? AND id = ?;`

In this command, I would like to check if location already exists in database.

Comment: Why it shouldn't? If you do not use multiple *AND* How you will get the needed result?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty normal practice. Just one comment better use conditions in selectivity order: first id, after location and is_deleted at end.
And remember about indexes that can improve queries performance

Comment: MySQL doesn't care at all about the order of `WHERE` conditions.